# What formula will allow me to increase or decrease a value and limit the total amount the value can be increased or decreased

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to create a quota tabulator that will adjust a quota value by .5 point for every full point increased or decreased AND will limit the total increase or decrease by a value of 3 points.

This is the formula that I've come up with so far:

=if(or(or(C2-B2<=0+1),or(C2-B2>=0+1)),(mround((C2-B2)*0.5+B2,0.5)),B2)

This formula correctly adjusts the quota when the value is decreased. [image: Correct Quota Calculation]

It does not correctly adjust the quota when the value is increased. [image: Incorrect Quota Calculation]

Regarding the limit by which a value is increased or decreased regardless of the score that is entered, and referencing the pictures above, the updated quota should not be able to be more than 21 points or less than 15 points. I have no idea how to do that.

My problem is that I don't understand what I'm doing so I don't know what is making the formula calculate decreasing values correctly but increasing values incorrectly. And, again, I don't even know where to begin to make the formula limit the value's increase or decrease. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Does this formula work for you? `ifs(C2>B2+6,B2+3,B2-6>C2,B2-3,C2<=B2,B2+ceiling(C2-B2)/2,B2<C2,B2+floor(C2-B2)/2)`

It produces the following output when inputted in cell `D2` and transposed downward:

[image: A Google Sheets table of Starting Quota, Dooks Score, and Updated Quota, with values for seventeen players.]

Here's how it works:

- `C2>B2+6,B2+3`: If the difference between Dooks Score and Starting Quota is 6 or greater, return the Starting Quota +3 to limit the Updated Quota from increasing by more than 3.
- `B2-6>C2,B2-3`: If the difference between Dooks Score and Starting Quota is −6 or lesser, return the Starting Quota −3 to limit the Updated Quota from decreasing by more than −3.
- `C2<=B2,B2+ceiling(C2-B2)/2`: If B2 is greater than (or equal) to C2, then return the difference between the two, rounded up, and divided by two.
- `B2<C2,B2+floor(C2-B2)/2)`: If C2 is greater than B2, then return the difference between the two, rounded down, and divided by two.

The reason for the third and fourth parts of the `IFS` statement to be separated is to make the number always round closer to 0 (e.g. preventing `-2.1` from being rounded to `-3` instead of `-2`, which is what I believe you want.

Comment: That does the trick nicely, thanks! I also really appreciate the explanation. I like to know why an answer is what it is. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

```
=MIN(ROUNDDOWN(ABS(B2-C2))*0.5,3)*SIGN(C2-B2)+B2
```

It first takes absolute value of difference between starting quota and score then rounds it down and multiplies by 0.5 points.

MIN() limits result to 3.

Then we multiply it by SIGN() depending is we have increase or decrease and add starting quota.

Comment: Also very helpful. Thank you!